# Splitting data from a sheet into more sheets in the same workbook

Tags: vba, excel

exporting data from a CAD software I obtain a single workbook and the first sheet contains the list of the components we need to buy. The components are listed in groups and I need to split each group into more sheets. One sheet for each group. At the beginning of each group there is a merged cell containing the group name (that could be different at any exportation) and two rows below a common row:

Part Number   --   Customer Part Number   --   Supplier Part Number   --   Supplier Name    ....

At the end of each group there is an empty row.

In which way could I split the groups?

I am using this code:

```
Sub parse_data()
Dim lr As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim vcol, i As Integer
Dim icol As Long
Dim myarr As Variant
Dim title As String
Dim titlerow As Integer
vcol = 1
Set ws = Sheets("BOM All")
lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
title = "A1:J1"
titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
icol = ws.Columns.Count
ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"
For i = 2 To lr
On Error Resume Next
If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
End If
Next
myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
ws.Columns(icol).Clear
For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
Else
Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
End If
ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
Next
ws.AutoFilterMode = False
ws.Activate
End Sub
```

But:
1) this code is made to split in new sheets the rows referring on the content in the firs column. So if I insert a new column and for each group of data I use the same name in each cell in the first column I can make the code understand where it is the starting point and the end point to split the groups. But this code does not work properly neither for its purpose.

2) I tryed to modify it to make it to recognize the common line I have in the workbook to make it understand where to split.

But I failed.

I would like to split the original file ***without*** inserting manually the first column.

Screenshot:

http://imageshack.com/a/img163/1508/2vx0.jpg

Comment: I'm a little confused by the "At the beginning of each group there is a merged cell containing the group name (that could be different at any exportation) and two rows below a common row" part. Could you post some sample data?

Comment: You should post some code and tell us where you're stuck. This is not the place to find someone to completely handle a task.

Comment: If you have no idea where to start at all, I'd recommend taking a look at [looping in VBA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221353%28v=office.11%29.aspx) and the [`IsEmpty` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264227.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The key to this is finding a way to detect the row in which data on a new group begins.

The code below looks for cells in the first column that starts with Design and on encountering it creates a new sheet and copies rows to this sheet until another cell in the first column that starts with design.

It should work on your spreadsheet without the column that you inserted.

```
Sub parse_data1()

Dim lr As Long
Dim wsParse As Worksheet
Dim wsNewSheet As Worksheet
Dim lRowNumber As Long
Dim lNewSheetRowNumber As Long

Set wsParse = Sheets("BOM All")

lr = wsParse.Cells(wsParse.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For lRowNumber = 1 To lr

    'Each time Design is encountered a new sheet is created
    'LTrim removes any leading blank spaces
    'The Left function is selecting the first 6 characters in the cell
    If Left(LTrim(wsParse.Cells(lRowNumber, 1).Value), 6) = "Design" Then
        Set wsNewSheet = Sheets.Add
        lNewSheetRowNumber = 1
    End If

    'Copying the each row to the new sheet(s)
    wsParse.Rows(lRowNumber).Copy
    wsNewSheet.Cells(lNewSheetRowNumber, 1).Select
    wsNewSheet.Paste
    lNewSheetRowNumber = lNewSheetRowNumber + 1

Next lRowNumber

End Sub
```